# PHP how to calculate total values multiple of 3

Tags: php

i have table product and i want to count the values ​​per three columns.

```
No   Name       Qty
--------------------
1    p.A        2
2    p.b        5
3    p.c        3
4    p.d        1
5    p.e        3
------------------


expected output:
No   Name       Qty
--------------------
1    p.A        2
2    p.b        5
3    p.c        3
------------------
total_qty : 10     
----------------


No   Name       Qty
------------------
4    p.d        1
5    p.e        3
------------------
total_qty  : 4

current result :
No   Name       Qty
--------------------
1    p.A        2
2    p.b        5
3    p.c        3
------------------
total_qty : 10     
----------------


No   Name       Qty
------------------
4    p.d        1
5    p.e        3
------------------
total_qty  : 14
```

so the calculation in table no. 1 is correct, but the results of table no. 2 calculate the value of the entire table

code sample implementation:
https://gist.github.com/kardotinambunan12/0410fffb4162ee07d2dc290ff2c9ea05 and

https://gist.github.com/kardotinambunan12/a9ab8f654531adbe14b74633720efed1

Comment: Show your code please (I believe it is a sql query ?)

Comment: Without seeing your code I examined your expected and current output. Notice that the sum that is `14` is what it should be *plus* the previous sum: `4 + 10 = 14`  .... So in your code make sure you are resetting whichever variable you have storing *total_qty* to `0`.

Comment: the sample code can be seen here. https://gist.github.com/kardotinambunan12/0410fffb4162ee07d2dc290ff2c9ea05   and in here   : https://gist.github.com/kardotinambunan12/a9ab8f654531adbe14b74633720efed1

Comment: You need to extract the exact code you are using, add it to the question and demonstrate how it is erroring.  The base query, seems simple enough, group by name and sum(qty).  If you are trying to then subset the full result set, using something like modulus 3, then you simply need a total variable you reset whenever you start a new table.  The code you linked seems to bear little resemblence to your question.

Comment: actually the original code is in the link, the question table above is just a simple code sample